# Changing urls in the address bar after page-forward navigation to create bookmarkable urls

Tags: javascript, url, jsf, browser

JSF by default, uses a internal page forward mechanism instead of page redirect. This, however, leaves me with a bit of problem. I need to create bookmark-able urls but since the url doesn't change with navigation, I am afraid as to how I can modify the urls after page forward navigation so that different pages may be properly bookmarked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should design your website that way that you use POST only for real form submits and thus not for page-to-page navigation. For that you should use GET instead with `<h:link>` (since JSF 2.0 only), `<h:outputLink>` or plain `<a>`. You should not use a POST form for plain page-to-page navigation. If you are restricted by design or component limitations, then your best bet is to add a `<redirect/>` to the navigation case, or adding `faces-redirect=true` parameter to the outcome value (since JSF 2.0 only).

Comment: oh.. yes I missed out these `<h:link>` and `<h:outputLink>` tags as everywhere in examples I just saw commandLinks most of times. You really saved me .. thanks!

Comment: but incase I couldnt use these tags because of some limitation would it have been preferable to use `faces-redirect=true` because as far as I understand that there is a downside for redirection

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the HTML5 `pushState`. You can learn more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history